# How to parse Retrofit 2 response to display data?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I want to display the "title" from the API(http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) using Retrofit 2 and Gson(or GsonFormat, i'm not really sure),
I have created the following classes,
Modal.java

```
package arpit.retrodemo;

public class Modal {
    private String title;
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
}
```

APIService interface,

```
package arpit.retrodemo;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.http.GET;

public interface APIService {
    @GET("/posts")
    Call<List<Modal>> getDetails();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package arpit.retrodemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    private APIService service;
    private static List<Modal> users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<List<Modal>> userList = service.getDetails();
        userList.enqueue(new Callback<List<Modal>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Modal>> response) {
                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    Log.d("find", "response.isSuccess");
                    // to parse the API reponse(in JSON) to display, say, "title" from the API response
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d("findError", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Json format

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }
]
```

so i get the response from API in onResponse method but

How can i store each title in an object of Modal.java class and a List "users" will contain all the objects of Modal.java so that i can later display the titles using the Iterator on "users" List.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621240/parse-a-nested-json-with-retrofit-2-0/34621436#34621436

Comment: You may be getting list of modal class in your onResponse method inside response.body(). Can you please check but you are getting in your response.body() ?

Comment: There is correction required in your Json, it is not standard as per the above comments.

Answer (score 1):

1). First of all, please add setter function for title as well in your Modal class.

2). You can find the list of modal class from `response.body()`. For example.

```
   @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Modal>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccess()){
                List<Modal> titlesList=response.body();
            }
        }
```

Comment: its giving null pointer exception when i try to access titlesList using for each as     `for(Modal mod : titlesList){Log.d("find", mod.getTitle());}`

Comment: have you debugged your code? are you getting null in your response.body() ?

Comment: Hey its working fine, i did a terrible silly mistake there, thanks for the help,
and can you please also look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832191/unable-to-fetch-json-object-and-array-in-retrofit-2 , i'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: glad that it worked..:)

Answer (score 0):

If all other things are fine you can use this piece of code.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Modal>>() { // object can be String here
        }.getType();
        List<Modal> list = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().string(), listType);
```