# Retrieving Retrofit request from server and putting it to <List<Model>>

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm having an issue. I'm trying to get JSON from server via Retrofit, but I'm not able to convert it back to list based on database model.

Code goes like this:

```
public void syncFromCloud() throws SQLException, IOException {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(IntentConstants.API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    FoodLogInterface service = retrofit.create(FoodLogInterface.class);
    Call<List<FoodLog>> call = service.getFoodLogList(mFoodLogs);
}
```

where I'm connecting via Retrofit like this:

```
public interface FoodLogInterface {

@GET("http://pastebin.com/6Uaq4ZHW")
Call<List<FoodLog>> getFoodLogList(@Query ("http://pastebin.com/UhE12m3m") List<FoodLog> foodLog);
```

}

I'm able to get GSON from here, but I'm not able to put data bac to the mFoodLogs list.

This is the JSON I want to put back in class, also, I'm retrieving it from pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/6Uaq4ZHW

```
[{
    "date": "Thursday, February 4, 2016 at 1:28 PM",
    "dateEdited": "Thursday, February 4, 2016 at 1:28 PM",
    "description": "",
    "id": "6d15cf24-3f0a-4fed-814f-1c16fe93ebd2",
    "title": "yhytt",
    "isSavedToCloud": false,
    "isDeleted": false
}, {
    "date": "Thursday, February 4, 2016 at 1:31 PM",
    "dateEdited": "Thursday, February 4, 2016 at 1:31 PM",
    "description": "",
    "id": "f3e7c018-04e7-428d-813b-36712bf0821d",
    "title": "yhytt",
    "isSavedToCloud": false,
    "isDeleted": false
}]
```

Comment: I can't understand you by *not able to put data bac* can you explain ?

Comment: also take look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621240/parse-a-nested-json-with-retrofit-2-0/34621436#34621436)

Comment: I need to convert JSON from web to back to list, and i need to put that list in mFoodLogs list. That is what i mean by putting data back.

Comment: If my answer link not helped you let me know may be I can help you

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need to store the returned json to mFoodLogs variable. Why do you need to pass mFoodLogs as a parameter in your service call?

I would suggest making the following changes.

1.Remove call and instead return a list directly. Also remove the query parameter that you were passing.

```
public interface FoodLogInterface {

@GET("http://pastebin.com/6Uaq4ZHW")
    List<FoodLog> getFoodLogList();
}
```

2.Assign the returned value directly to mFoodLogs

```
public void syncFromCloud() throws SQLException, IOException {
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(IntentConstants.API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
  FoodLogInterface service = retrofit.create(FoodLogInterface.class);
  mFoodLogs = service.getFoodLogList();
}
```

If your FoodLog class contains all the attributes returned in the json then the values should be set properly in mFoodLogs